# What is the recommended way to install packages not in `nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix`

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

I would like to install [elementary-terminal](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/desktops/pantheon/apps/elementary-terminal/default.nix). This package is 
not in `nixpkgs/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix` and I suppose it is therefore not sufficient to just add `elementary-terminal` into `configuration.nix`

What is the recommended way to install such packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some packages are namespaced to group them together or avoid potential conflicting names, in this case it's under `pantheon`.

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:
{
  environment.systemPackages =
    [ pkgs.pantheon.elementary-terminal
    ];
}
```

To figure this out use, `nix-env -q`, `nix search` or even nix-index to show the corresponding attribute path of a package.

```sh
$ nix-env -f '<nixpkgs>' -qaP elementary-terminal
pantheon.elementary-terminal  elementary-terminal-5.3.3
```